# What language/framework would be best for a lightweight cross platform GUI graphing application?

Tags: gui, cross-platform, graphs

Hoping this is the correct community to ask this question.

I am looking to write a desktop application to analyse motorsport data. The application will need to work offline without internet and it would be nice if at the end it is easily installable on friends computers without the need to "manually" run a server and then have to know to open a browser and go to localhost for example or run scripts.

I will develop it on Mac and would like it to also run on Windows and it would be a bonus if it was easy to move to mobile later.

The app would send a HTTP request using some data the user has selected in drop downs for example, to an embedded device that is connected locally over Wi-Fi using a hotspot from the device. It will receive the data and then graph it. If not connected to the device it would be nice to have the ability to read/open the data from files on the filesystem that had be downloaded from the device previously. I'd like to be able to make the graphs interactive, for example, hovering over one graph will highlight related data on other graphs.

Currently as a stop gap I use Python scripts and plotly to display the data for me, but this isn't interactive (without Dash).

I am an embedded C++ engineer that can dabble in Python and HTML/CSS/JS so have little knowledge in this space. I'd have to learn the new language and want to make sure I choose the correct one.

I had thought about using Kotlin with Compose as its multi platform and has the ability to move to mobile.

I have seen some micro web frameworks mentioned, but I'm unsure if I can end up with something that doesn't require the internet and a basic "app" at the end that anyone could click and run/use.

I have had a suggestion of a game engine like godots, I am not sure if it will have strong enough graph support.

I had maybe thought about using dash and plotly with any of the supported languages. Although again, not sure if I can get the easy to use "app" at the end. I'm also not sure if this lets me do other simple things like drop downs to enter data for the request I mentioned above or the ability to upload/open the data files.

Some examples of the types of graphs I'd like to produce:

- [Multiple graphs with a common X axis and track map](https://www.bosch-motorsport.com/content/downloads/Raceparts/Images/jpg/70949771__Web.jpg)
- [Interactive graph with track map](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwY4yMQCQ-9UytrkDa0jKmHlOYfm3PgqTFY7nizVGViA&s)
- [Bit fancier than I'm going for but this type of idea](https://www.renovatio-dev.com/images/vtelemetry-pro/vtelemetry-pro-live-telemetry-software-analysis-sim.jpg)

Would you choose any of the options I mention above or is there something better out there that I am missing?